# Hide ModLoad messages in windbg?

Tags: windbg

Is it possible to stop windbg from outputting `ModLoad` messages?

```
ModLoad: 77080000 7721d000   C:\Windows\system32\SETUPAPI.dll
ModLoad: 75ef0000 75f17000   C:\Windows\system32\CFGMGR32.dll
ModLoad: 76340000 763cf000   C:\Windows\system32\OLEAUT32.dll
```

I couldn't find relevant stuff with google

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use either menu Debug->Event Filters...
Set Load Module to ignore

or in the sx command to suppress output from the load module event

```
ntdll!DbgBreakPoint:
779b000c cc              int     3
0:001> sxi ld
```

Answer (score 0):

If using the newer WinDbg Preview, the Event Filters can be found in File > Settings > Events & Exceptions. There, you can set Events > Load Module on all modules to Ignore.